# Percentage of screen size as way to find a consistent point on screen, independently from the resolution

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate some tasks, and one problem I often find is working with system panels at different resolutions.

I am looking for a way to get to the buttons on a system panel, independently from the resolution. My assumption is that the panel appear always in the same position; independently from the resolution, so if I can get a way to translate the resolution coordinates, to something more absolute, I may be able to click that button, no matter the resolution.

If I use percentage as way to find the coordinates, instead of pixels, would that solve my problem?

Something like this:

- read resolution (example: 1920x1080)
- on 1920x1080, my button is located at points `x=920` and `y=180`
- transform the values from pixels to percentages, using `val = 100*(position/resolution)` for X and Y values
- Once I have the percentage position, if I go to a different computer that use a resolution like 1024x768, I can convert back that percentage value in a pixel value, using `position = (val/100)*resolution`, for X and Y values
- At this point, I have the values of X and Y to move the mouse to that specific point, which should be in the same general area of where the button I want to press is located.

Is this feasible or is it a waste of time, since the percentage is not a feasible value? In which case, how could I work around the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bad solution, use the element id or a css selector

Comment: Unless the objects happen to be laid out directly on the top-level document, or something floating over that document or the like, they're probably not going to be at a fixed percentage of the way across. Calculating the right position usually takes a complicated set of equations that… well, if you wanted to write the CSS parser and layout engine, you might as well add a renderer and a JS engine and you'd have your own browser. Better to just ask the browser—that already did all that work—to locate it by CSS selector.

Comment: Sadly the system panels do not have ID or CSS selectors; I have to manually move the mouse pointer to the location. The system panels and prompts are always foreground; so far I had no problems automating the screen using one resolution though; which is why I did try to look for a way to not have to hardcode specific sets of coordinates, based on the various resolutions available.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?